# I am creating PEM file for push notification but i am getting error?

Tags: ios

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in /Users/akshay/Desktop/n/pushchat.p12
```

664:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-47.2/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:150:
Akshays-Mac-mini:Desktop akshay$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pemopenssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in/Users/akshay/Desktop/n/pushchat.p12

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate to the directory where the **pushchat.p12** stored in **terminal**. Use **cd** command for this .After that, just use the below command

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in pushchat.p12

Answer (score 0):

i used this some command;this is ok.

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem    

$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12


$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem

$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in PushChatCert.pem -inkey PushChatKey.pem -certfile CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -name "aps_development" -out aps_development.p12
```